# Export DataGridView to Excel File

Tags: c#, datagridview

Can you say me, how can i save the contents of DataGridView to Exel File with the Formatting cells Backcolor/Forecolor? I have DGV like this:
[image]

And when I try to Export Data to Excel I get the data, but without Forecolor, I have tried a several of ways, but it does not work! Beforehand Thank you!

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "export.xls";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\export.xls");
            ToCsV1(dataGridView1, sfd.FileName);
        }  
}



private void ToCsV1(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        // Export titles:
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
        // Export data.
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Excel does the Cell colours independently doesn't it? As in I'm not sure (without some extensive coding) that it can be done?

Comment: CSV is just a text file with the raw data. If you want to export the formatting, you will have to create a native Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

try to export to ExcelXML

Example:

```
 using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileDialog.OpenFile(), Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        if (format == "XML")
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                            writer.WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?>");
                            writer.WriteLine("<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\">");
                            writer.WriteLine("<DocumentProperties xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">");
                            writer.WriteLine("<Author></Author>");
                            writer.WriteLine("<Created>" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToLongDateString() + "</Created>");
                            writer.WriteLine("<LastSaved>" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToLongDateString() + "</LastSaved>");
                            writer.WriteLine("<Company></Company>");
                            writer.WriteLine("<Version>12.00</Version>");
                            writer.WriteLine("</DocumentProperties>");

                            if (showGroupHeaders)
                                AddStyles(writer, groupDesc.Count());

                            writer.WriteLine(
                                "<Worksheet ss:Name=\"Silverlight Export\" xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\">");
                            writer.WriteLine("<Table>");
                        }

                        writer.Write(text.ToString());
                        if (format == "XML")
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("</Table>");
                            writer.WriteLine("</Worksheet>");
                            writer.WriteLine("</Workbook>");
                        }

                        writer.Close();
                    }
```

Where AddStyle Like this:

```
    private static void AddStyles(StreamWriter writer, int groupCount)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("<Styles>");

                for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
                {
                    int shift = i % _headerColor.Count();
                    var color = _headerColor[shift];
                    writer.WriteLine("<Style ss:ID=\"st{0}\">", i + 1);
                    writer.WriteLine("<Interior ss:Color=\"#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}\" ss:Pattern=\"Solid\"/>", color.R, color.G, color.B);
                    writer.WriteLine("</Style>");
                }

                writer.WriteLine("</Styles>");
            }
```

And Set cell backcolor:

```
string.Format("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"st{0}\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">{1}</Data></Cell>", style, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-style-formatting/202) is an example using `GemBox.Spreadsheet` component to work with Excel files and cell formatting.